# array_key_exists(): error Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle

I have a guzzle method that posting and I get the error

`array_key_exists():` The first argument should be either a string or an integer

My form is a simple post method form

```
<form action="{{URL::asset('/send/confirmation')}}" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   <input type="hidden" value="{{$order->id}}">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter your name">
           <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">By adding your name you are confirming your are authorized to sign this order and any conditions.</small>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="position">Position</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" aria-describedby="positionHelp" placeholder="Enter your position within the company">
        <small id="positionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">By adding your name you are confirming your are authorized to sign this order and any conditions.</small>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btngenius">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then my controller picks up the $request object and send the data

```
//Confirm Order
    public function confirmOrder(Request $request) {
        $id = $request->get('id');
        $name = $request->get('name');
        $position = $request->get('position');

        $response = (new GuzzleHttp\Client)->post(getenv('API_MICRO_URL') . '/orders/send/copy', [
            'form_params' => [
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $name,
                'position' => $position
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.session()->get('token.access_token'),
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);
        return response('all signed up');
    }
}
```

And im straight up returning that error, but not sure what I can see wrong

Comment: which version of guzzle you are using ?

Comment: Minor changes required in form and request. I've answered, please try and let me know if it work for you. Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you check all input fields in form? You have not mentioned name attribute. How can you suppose you will get param id, name etc.. without defined name in input filed?

Answer (score 0):

Do these changes:

```
$id = $request->id;
$name = $request->name;
$position = $request->position;
```

You have not setup **name** attribute into any of these input fields inside **FORM**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$order->id}}">
```

Hope work for you.